# Flops of the computation of symmetric matrix $A$ to the power of $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, complexity

What is the cost in terms of flops for the computation of $A$ to the power of $p$, where $p$ is a positive integer and $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: p is a positive integer

Comment: Welcome to scicomp. Have tried working it out for a small sizes? How many Operatiions do you need for a 2X2 symmetric matrix? If you have done that for a p=1,2,3 then you might be able to guess the underlying rule. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is $p$ small or large?

Comment: p is small but A is a large matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in $O(n^3)$ floating point operations by diagonalizing the matrix and applying the spectral theorem.

Comment: let's just say that applying the spectral theorem is not an option

Comment: You should probably edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for?